# using query string

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, query-string

I have 3 users: `admin`, `user1` and `user2`, and they're from 3 different tables in the database,  they all go to the same page and I have to show the user's information based on the user's ID  ...

How can I do that using query string?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Sounds like all you want is pass the user ID in the querystring, such as `?UserId={0}` ...

Comment: You might want to add more context here.  Why are they in different tables?  How are you uniquely identifying the users?  What do you want the page to display about the users?  (Please don't tell me you're using the query string to identify the current _authenticated_ user.)  What information is being passed on the query string?  Are you talking about building the query string on a hyperlink, or about using the query string to fetch data from the database?

Comment: Would you give a little more info about your data tables?  It sounds like a union may solve your problem, but I would like to see more before I answer your question.

Comment: Sounds like what the asker is talking about is three types of users and, instead of having one user table with an indicator column to determin what type of user they are, there's a separate table for each type of user.  If that's how it's designed, he's going to need to pass a type indicator through the query string along with the ID.

Answer (score 0):

This **isn't best practices** for passing userid's from page to page, but you can accomplish by doing this in your code.

```
dim userid as string = request.querystring("userid")
```

Answer (score 0):

If user come from three different tables UNION will help combine three queries into one. Something like

```
 (select username, access from table1)
 UNION 
 (select username, access from table2)
 UNION
 (select username, access from table2)
```

Note: Can hard code acess depending on which table the user is from

```
 (select username, 'Admin' from table1)
 UNION 
 (select username,  'User1' from table2)
 UNION
 (select username,  'User2' from table2)
```

On your page you can load differently depending on access

Answer (score 0):

Ever consider using the membership framework. You could then use the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` directly without having to continuously query your database yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. you send user ID. to the other side like

```
page.aspx?Id=1
```

but unfortunately I can not from what you write see how you will receive and use your query. but the easy way is with example a datalist to show the data and then a `SqlDataSource` to bind the data with the datalist control.

When you configure the data source you select the columns of the table you like. and then press the WHERE button and then you will get to this screen. [image: datasource configuration]

Here you first select the column as your QueryString should be equal with
then you add this condition and close the datasouce configuration screen and then all the data that will show in the datalist will check whether any of CUSTOMER_ID which has the same ID as in the Qureysting.

Some will probably think this is girly way to do it but it works.
hope you can use it.